# WMI pulls current user even if never logged in

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am new to powershell, and I am attempting to create a CSV from an excel file for comparison sake to see who is currently logged into a computer. However, I'm running into an odd issue where sometimes the script will pull the same user multiple times even if they've never logged into a computer. Here is my full code. I know there is a lot of optimization that can be done (and parts that need to be removed, those should be noted). I assume I've misused Get-WMIObject or something similar, can anyone see why it would pull that information like it is?

```
$csvRunFile = "test.csv"
$output = "Results_$(Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd).csv"

#Import the created csv. 
$csv = import-csv $CsvRunFile

$results = foreach($csv_line in $csv) {
    $ctag = $csv_line.ctag
    $test_ping = test-connection $ctag -Count 1 -Quiet


    #If the computer is pingable (IE: Online)
    switch ($test_ping) {
        $true {
            #Pull the actual logged in user. 
            $Username = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ctag -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Username.Split("\\")[1]

            #If the last modified folder is 'public' put an error, otherwise pull the username's information from AD. 
            #This was from when it pulled from the \User folder rather than the last log in, this is probably removeable. 
            if ($Username -eq "Public") {
                $ADName = "No User"
            } else {
                $ADName = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username
                $ADName = $ADName.Name
            } #end If
        }#end Switch:True

    #Show there was an error when pinging the computer. 
        $false {$ADName = "ERROR"}
    }#end Switch

    #write the results the new output CSV. 
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        CTAG = $ctag
        Username = $ADName
    }#end PSCustom Object

    $result
} #end foreach

#Turn the .txt into a CSV so it can be manually compared to the list in the original excel file.
$results | Export-Csv -path $output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a leftover-value in `$UserName` for some reason or `$ADName` is still it's old value because you tried to run `Get-ADUser -Identity $null` when there was no user logged on (WMI returns `$null` when there's no user logged in).

I also changed your ping-test from a switch to an if-test just to cleanup the code. I've never seen `Public` being returned, but I left it as it doesn't really hurt either.

Try:

```
#If the computer is pingable (IE: Online)
if($test_ping) {
    #Clear username var just to be safe
    $Username = $null
    #Pull the actual logged in user. 
    $Username = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ctag -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Username | ? { $_ } | % { $_.Split("\\")[1] }

    #If the last modified folder is 'public' put an error, otherwise pull the username's information from AD. 
    #This was from when it pulled from the \User folder rather than the last log in, this is probably removeable. 
    if (($Username -eq "Public") -or ($Username -eq $null)) {
        $ADName = "No User"
    } else {
        $ADName = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username
        $ADName = $ADName.Name
    } #end If username public
} else { $ADName = "ERROR"}
```

Comment: I've used the updated code, and it does the same thing. I've attempted to put in a clear-variable at the end of the loop to try to clean out the variables, but it throws an error, it seems it's trying to clear the value inside of the variable, which hasn't fixed the issue. However, looking at the sheet, that does seem to be the problem, rather than pulling the $null value, it's just repeating the previous $username that was defined.

Comment: Try updated answer, it should work, just like the last one except I handled a "call method on null-value"-error in your code. If it doesn't work, then you need to add a breakpoint in the script and debug it when you actually have one of the wrong values, because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: That was it, looks like the clear-variable was not actually clearing the variable, but yours works (Either that, or the extra bits in the get-wmi that you used, not sure what that does, will look it up).

Comment: The added part to the wmi-line is `Where-Object { $_ } | Foreach-Object { #your split operation }`. If Username was `$null`, then calling `.Split("\\")` would normally cause an error. What the added code does is take the username, continue only if the object is not null (`where`) and if it's not null, run the split operation (`foreach`) . If username was `$null` then the command would simply return and store `$null` (no output)